# A system call to dump information about all system processes and the threads in a multithreaded program

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

How can I make a system call in linux (I'm using ubuntu) to dump information about all the processes in the system and also about the threads in my multithreaded program? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You can use the `ps` command: `ps -eLf`

Comment: I have to actually add a new system call and then call this system call on my multithreaded program after threads are created. How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you need a *system call*? you can simply use `system("ps -eLf");`

Comment: Only because its a requirement,  if not this would've work like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Is this for educational usage? I can't see other reasons for a system call. The kernel supports all that information through the `/proc` filesystem. (And this is what ps is using)....

Comment: Yes, it is for my own education, I am not attending school, but saw this project online and started to try it out. In other words, I am teaching myself.

Comment: Ok, understood. I suggest to read the kernel sources and learn how the relevant information is written to the `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

First Step is to implement a system call to list the processes.

The kernel stores the list of processes in a circular doubly linked list called the `task list`. Each element in the task list is a process descriptor of the type `struct task_struct`, which is defined in `<linux/sched.h>`. The process descriptor contains all the information about a specific process.

The `task_struct` structure contains all the information that the kernel has and needs about a process. The process descriptor contains the data that describes the executing program open files, the process's address space, pending signals, the process's state, and much more.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

asmlinkage long sys_proclist(void*)
{
    struct task_struct *task;

    for_each_process(task) {
        /* this prints the name and PID of each task */
        printk("%s[%d]\n", task->comm, task->pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The macro `for_each_process(task)` iterates over the entire task list. On each iteration, task points to the next task in the list.

Once you have the implementation of the system call in a `proclist.c` file,
now you have to add this system call to your kernel source, recompile the kernel, install and reboot to use it in user space.

**To compile the kernel:** do a little bit of reading (follow a tutorial) before doing it, you will break your system if anything goes wrong.

**NOTE:** File paths and file names provided in any tutorial may vary depending on the kernel version so be careful.

Comment: where do you get `task` from?

Comment: Thank you so much, will try this now... Compile and install modules correct?

Comment: Inside the kernel, `tasks` are typically referenced directly by a pointer to their `task_struct` structure present in the kernel stack. the macro retrieves that address of each `tast_struct` one by one for all the processes running on the system.

Comment: https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/ follow this tutorial, for adding new system call, its easy to read.

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you so much.. happy I found help here and I am glad I learned this is very interesting